# Php not parsing new line in variable obtained from GET request

Tags: php, csv

I am writing a plugin in which I need the user to be able to download a csv created on the fly (I don't want to use up server space). I have the text I need to print to csv pinted in a hidden element in a form, which I then echo and create csv using fopen and fclose.  The problem is that new lines are not being parsed.  I have tried adding slashes, closing the variable in double quotes, and output buffering. I have also set auto_detect_line_endings to true.  Here is my code.

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$data = $_POST['csv_holder'];
echo $data;
fclose($fp);
```

and the html:

```
<form id = 'wcds_$post_id_csv_download' action ='$download_file' method='post'><input   type ='hidden' name = 'csv_holder' id ='wcds_download_csv_$post_id_value' value ='$wcds_item_details_string'><input type ='submit' id ='wcds_download_csv_$post_id' class ='wcds_download_button'</form>
```

example `$wcds_item_details_string`: `1,2,3\r\n4,5,6\r\n7,8,9`

```
$wcds_item_details_string = get_the_content();
    //sanitise for html
    $wcds_item_details_string = htmlspecialchars ( $wcds_item_details_string, ENT_QUOTES );
```

Tried string replace :

```
$replace = '&#92';
    $backslash = '\\';
    $wcds_item_details_string = str_replace( $backslash, $replace, $wcds_item_details_string );
```

Figured it out, the database was returning the variable as a single quoted string.  I just had to use string replace to change the line breaks to double quoted.  Final code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$data = $_POST['csv_holder'];
    $data= str_replace(  '\r\n', "\r\n", $data );
echo "{$data}";
fclose($fp);
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: How big is the CSV? URL parameters are limited in length, you should use `method=POST`.

Comment: However, that shouldn't have any effect on newlines. The browser should use percent-encoding, which will encode the newlines properly.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that, will try.  However still have the problem

Comment: What are you using `$fp` for?

Comment: To my understanding, $fp is a reference to the file opened by fopen.

Comment: I know. You open it and close it, but never do anything with it. What's the point?

Comment: The code is the file opened by the forms action, so it downloads the csv to the users computer, and then goes straight back to the page, as no output was created.

Comment: Edited to show html and post method

Comment: When you create `$wcds_item_details_string`, are you using single or double quotes? Because escape sequences are not processed in single quotes in PHP.

Comment: It's a wordpress plugin.  $wcds_item_details_string is being created from post content inside the loop

Comment: I think the problem is that the `value` attribute can't contain newline characters, and `htmlspecialchars` doesn't convert them to entities. Neither does `htmlentities`. I think you may need to use `str_replace()` to convert them.

Comment: Still not working.  The characters are in the csv file, they just haven't been parsed as new lines.  I may have to try a different method for this.

Comment: What characters are in the CSV file? Literal `\n`, or literal `%10`?

Comment: literal \r\n Their just printed into the cells with the contents

Comment: I think the problem is with WP, it's putting literal escape sequences into the string rather than the control characters. You can use `str_replace()` to replace these with entities.

Comment: Afraid not, already tried as per your previous comments

Comment: Please, try my answer, I have tested it, it should work for you. You have to change you data writting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as the answer, as this was what solved my problem.  The issue with fputs over echoing to the output buffer is a subject for another question.

The problem was the data was being output as a single quoted strings, so I had to replace the single quoted returns with double quoted ones.

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$data = $_POST['csv_holder'];
$data= str_replace(  '\r\n', "\r\n", $data );
echo "{$data}";
fclose($fp);
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I have read comments under your question, but I really dont understand, why you open file, save reference to `$fp`, and then echo `$data` from your CSV, instead of using function `fputs`:

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$data = $_POST['csv_holder'];
$data= str_replace(  '\r\n', "\r\n", $data );
echo "{$data}";
fclose($fp);
```

Try this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$data = $_POST['csv_holder'];
$data= str_replace(  '\r\n', "\r\n", $data );
fputs($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

Or there is exactly option to store CSV data; you can use this function:

```
function outputCSV($data) {
  $fp = fopen("php://output", 'w');

  function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
    fputcsv($filehandler, $vals, ';', '"');
  }

  array_walk($data, '__outputCSV', $fp);

  fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a php noob, so I'm learning as I go here. From what I understand, fputs requires a length, otherwise it stops when it encounters a 0? I looked at fwrite, which seems to do what I need, but as far as I can tell `php://` acts as an output buffer anyway. What is the benefit of using fputs or fwrite?