# What is the benefit of using fputs over echoing to the output buffer opened by fopen

Tags: php

Like the header says, I would like to know the benefit of using fputs over echoing to the output buffer opened by fopen.  I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782210/php-not-parsing-new-line-in-variable-obtained-from-get-request) and was advised I should be using fputs.  Why?

Example:

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$data = $_POST['csv_holder'];
echo $data;
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: There's no real benefit to calling `fopen()` to write to the output buffer in this context _at all_.  You set your headers (so PHP won't send the `Content-type: text/html` automatically) and subsequent output will go straight to the buffer. You gain nothing from `fopen()`.  A simple `echo` after the `header()` calls will do.  You do not need to `fopen('php://output')`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski I didn't know that :) If I hadn't specified headers would there be any benefit from fputs?

Comment: No not really. PHP would then send the HTML header on its own and echo your text.